# Don't split at spaces in jq output

Tags: bash, json, jq

I used jq to convert an array of words into an argument for a java program.

its like

```
arguments=$(jq '.nameField | "-i " + "\"" + . + "\""' file.json)

java .... $arguments  <-- No quotes wrapped around arguments.
```

**Expected output**: Java must read as `-i "Name 1" -i "Name 2"`, and "`Name 1`" should be read as one complete argument.

**Output received**: Java throws error as it read `"Name` , `1"`, `"Name`  and `2"` separately.

I want it to consider "Name 1" a single entity.

Comment: What should be read as one argument? Is it the whole string in `$arguments` or each `-i "Name 1"` bit, or are you referring to just `Name 1`?  I'm assuming that the double quotes should not be part of the argument, right?   It would be good to have an example input JSON document to test with as the `jq` expression seems to only return a single string (there's no array in your input), even though you mention multiple returned strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the arguments in an array.

Assuming the .nameField value never contains a newline:

```bash
readarray -t arguments < <(jq -r '.nameField | "-i", .' file.json)

java ... "${arguments[@]}"
```

The `jq`command emits the "-i" and each name on separate lines; the `readarray` command reads the lines into an array.

See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

---

For your code to work, you'll need `eval java ... $arguments`, which is generally not recommended

Comment: That assumes `.nameField` doesn't contain newline nor NUL characters. Better to use `@sh` in combination with `eval`. Or use `readarray -td ''` and make sure `jq` outputs the list NUL-delimited after having made sure the NULs *inside* the value have been removed or transformed (like `@sh` does)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```bash
eval "arguments=($(jq -r '.nameField | ["-i", .] | @sh' file.json))"
java ... "${arguments[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input JSON file contains several objects at its top-level, not in an array, but like this:

```json
{"nameField":"Name 1"}
{"nameField":"Name 2"}
{"nameField":"Name 3"}
{"nameField":"Name 4"}
{"nameField":"Name 5"}
```

... and that no `nameField` value contains any embedded newlines (or NULs), then use `jq` to pull out all the values and construct a `bash` array, `arguments`, like so:

```bash
arguments=()
while IFS= read -r name; do
    arguments+=( -i "$name" )
done < <( jq -r '.nameField' file.json )
```

Then call your Java code while expanding the array:

```bash
java ... "${arguments[@]}"
```

Note that the expansion `"${arguments[@]}"` must be quoted precisely like shown here, or the shell would split each value on any space or tab included in each value (and perform filename globbing on the generated strings).

If you want to pass JSON strings to your Java code (it's not clear from the question), remove the `-r` option from the invocation of `jq`.  This would pass the strings to the `java` command as if the arguments had been written `-i '"Name 1"' -i '"Name 2"'` etc., with literal double-quotes included in the arguments.  This removes the limitation that a `nameField` value cannot include embedded newlines or NULs (since these would be encoded as `\n` and `\u0000` respectively).